# How to do Harmonic Sum in O(lg n)?

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm

I read recently in Steven Skiena "Algorithms design manual book" that the harmonic Sum is of O(lg n). I understand how this is possible mathematically, but when i saw the recursive solution to it, which is the following:

```
public static double harmonic(int n) {
if(n == 1) {
    return 1.0;
} else {
    return (1.0 / n) + harmonic(n - 1);
}
```

}

I can not see how this is O(lg n), I see it as O(n). is this code above really lg(n) if so how ? if not can someone refer me to an example where this is the case ?

Comment: You are confusing asymptotic notation with time complexity analysis. The *value* of the sum of n terms is O(log n), this is not the same as the time it takes to compute that value. Asymptotic notation can be used to describe any function, not just functions whose outputs are running times.

Comment: sorry, but i don't get what u mean. What do u mean by functions whose outputs are running times?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion here is that big-O notation can be used not only for running times, but for the growth of functions in general.

As kaya3 comments, the **return value** of the function above is *O(lg n)*, which means it grows asymptotically as fast as *lg n* as you increase *n*. This is quite likely what the book is claiming. It is a mathematical property of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

The **running time** of the function, however, takes *O(n)* time. This is what you are claiming, and it is perfectly true (assuming constant-time arithmetics).

If you are still confused about how big-O notation can be used for purposes other than the running time of algorithms, I recommend you check its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).